# Apache JackRabbit, anyone have examples of webapps built with it?

Tags: jackrabbit

Does anyone have example websites that were built using this api?

I have found the following:

[Silver peas](http://www.silverpeas.org)

Does anyone have an example of another one?

Comment: http://www.liferay.com/

Answer (score 0):

Jahia jahia.org is another tool that uses JCR and jackrabbit
eXo plaeform uses JCR (bur its own implementation)

Answer (score 0):

[Apache Sling](http://sling.apache.org/) is a web app framework that uses Jackrabbit (and now Oak) for content storage. http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/JcrLinks has a number of links to applications that use it.